# SSL Certificate_Verify_Failed Reoccurred After Restart Discord.py

Tags: python, ssl, discord, raspbian

I had the following error running my discord bot specifically occurring on the line `client.run('TOKEN')` on **Raspbian**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/bot.py", line 162, in <module>
    client.run('OTI4MTQ2MzUwNDMwODg4MDM1.YdUhpg.J-Hw2jZqp_53xOQeqjD67up45T0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Bot $ python3.10 bot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/bot.py", line 162, in <module>
    client.run('OTI4MTQ2MzUwNDMwODg4MDM1.YdUhpg.J-Hw2jZqp_53xOQeqjD67up45T0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

When I input the solution yesterday I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5968) it seemed to resolve this issue and the bot was running perfectly fine. I'll include the solution below:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

I was absolutely mystified when I launched my Raspberry Pi this morning and the issue reoccurred. I tried the solution above again and it did not resolve the issue. Does anyone know why this occurred and what the solution is?

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these, I remember having similar issues once on a VirtualBox installation for some distro and I found this somewhere which fixed my issue (can't recall where exactly)

`pip install certifi`

then after that

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

`certifi` is a package that comes preinstalled with requests is what I know and sometimes you might not have it.

- PyPi:

  https://pypi.org/project/certifi/
- Github:

  https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi

Comment: Gave that a shot. No luck unfortunately

Comment: @lime can you try upgrading the package instead. `pip install -U certifi`

Comment: Still no luck. With both installs it returned `ca-certificates is already the newest version`. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ca-certificates but it still returned the same